# Sharing my paid app on my iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore, apple-id, apple-store

I have an iPhone 5 and need to buy an app which is quite expensive. The first question: if I want to use this app on my iPad (which has the same Apple ID), would I have to buy it again or not?

The second question: I am thinking about buying an iPhone 6 after 2-3 months and then selling my iPhone 5, would I have to buy this app again or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you purchase the app, it stays associated to the Apple ID you used. You can install it on other iOS devices, too.

Quoth [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074):

> You can associate your Apple ID with up to 10 devices, with a maximum of 5 computers at any time. Each computer must also be authorized using the same Apple ID.

You can re-install it on a new iOS device in the future. Remember to Erase All Content and Settings, and sign out of iCloud before you sell your iPhone 5.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a limit to the number of iDevices one can install the app on, I could be wrong, though.

Comment: It's a (relatively) new rule. http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/09/apple-id-account-device-limits-gain-attention/